# Can you safely close a file that was never opened?

Tags: c++, file-io, error-handling, ofstream

If I have a [`std::ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) that may or may not have been opened, is it safe to try to `close` regardless? In otherwords does `close()` do anything nasty (throw exception, etc) if `!is_open()`. For example

```
std::ofstream out;
if (some_condition)
{
    out.open(path, std::ios::out);
}
```

After I'm done with the file, can I just say

```
out.close();
```

Or should I first check

```
if (out.is_open())
    out.close();
```

The only description of [`std::basic_fstream::close`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/close) on cppreference is

> Closes the associated file.
>   Effectively calls `rdbuf()->close()`. If an error occurs during operation, `setstate(failbit)` is called.

Comment: You could just let the object go out of scope ...

Comment: Generally that is what I do, which is why I like `std::ofstream`, but in this particular case I would like the file to be closed earlier than it would otherwise be.

Comment: If you look on cppreference for [`std::ofstream::close`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/close/), you will see that the specific example of calling `close` on a not opened file is used. In summary, nothing nasty occurs, it just sets the failbit so anything you try to do with the `ofstream` afterwards might cause issues.

Comment: @R_Kapp that's not cppreference

Comment: @Cubbi: ... Where's my coffee?

Comment: cppreference now links that rdbuf->close to the filebuf close page, which is a lot more detailed

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It does exactly what cppreference says it will: the failbit will be set, and you can inspect it with the fail() method. For instance, the following prints "fail\n":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
        std::ofstream out;
        out.close();
        if (out.fail())
                std::cout << "fail" << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

In terms of interaction with the operating system, there's nothing there to close, but it's otherwise harmless.

Answer (score 8):

From the C++ standard, §27.9.1.4 [filebuf.members], paragraph 6:

> `basic_filebuf<charT,traits>* close();`
>          Effects: If `is_open() == false`, returns a null pointer.…

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can `close()` the file always, even the file is not opened.
No matter LINUX or Windows, I always `close()` without thinking they are opened or not.

From LINUX:

```
void
close()
{
     if (!_M_filebuf.close())
        this->setstate(ios_base::failbit);
}
```

Comment: "From LINUX" you mean libstdc++?

Comment: yes. The indentation is wired because the libstdc++ is formatted like that

Comment: Linux and Windows don't have anything to do with it. The question is about C++.